# How to trim chinese and japanses characters

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

SELECT LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM('     価格    '))) AS TrimmedString;

It gives ?? as output.

> How to put it here in function:

```
Create OR ALTER Function dbo.udf_GetTrimAndLower (@input NVARCHAR(max))
Returns NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(max);
    select @output = LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@input)));

    RETURN (@output);
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this. I've added extra spaces for display purpose.
You have to use the nvarchar data type.

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(N'       価格         ')) AS TrimmedString;
```

Comment: Your function works fine for me `select dbo.udf_GetTrimAndLower(N'       価格         ')`

Comment: Is there any way we can change in function only, instead of arguments for function???

Comment: Is there any way we can change in function only, instead of arguments for function???

Actually the value ' 価格 ' is coming from a function.
Like 
select dbo.udf_GetTrimAndLower(JSON_VALUE(PayloadBoth,'$.returnreason'))   AS ReturnReason

Comment: @SeanCoetzee Please have a look on my new comments.

Comment: the `JSON_VALUE` function returns the value in the same collation as the input value. So as long as `PayloadBoth` is an `nvarchar` the output will be too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean.

Comment: I tried but it's still giving '???????'

Please try with below query:

DECLARE @info NVARCHAR(100)='{"name":"  装用時の不快感  ","skills":["C#","SQL"]}'


SELECT dbo.udf_getTrimAndLower( JSON_VALUE(@info, '$.name')) AS JVal

Comment: DECLARE @info NVARCHAR(500)=N'{"name":" 装用時の不快感 ","skills":["C#","SQL"]}'

You need the **N'** after the equals sign